# Only allow traffic trough port 80 in firewall

Tags: windows-server-2008, firewall, windows-firewall

In our firewall we want to only allow port 80 and close all other ports. This is easy to do, but how can we test if the firewall is only allowing port 80.

How do you test and confirm that the firewall is configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap (https://nmap.org/) from another machine:

```
nmap -v your_host_or_ip_here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to scan your host to open ports, good tool is nmap from different location. You can do fast check just with

```
nmap your_hostname_or_ip
```

which just scan 1000 most common ports or with

```
nmap -p 1-65535 your_hostname_or_ip
```

you can scan all TCP ports. See man page to more info about testing UDP/ICMP ports, networks and so on. You should see report like this

```
Starting Nmap 6.47 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-10-13 15:12 CEST
Nmap scan report for example.com (93.184.216.34)
Host is up (0.15s latency).
Not shown: 997 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
80/tcp   open   http
443/tcp  open   https
1119/tcp closed bnetgame

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.46 seconds
```